# Maven Jsoup Missing Artifact Exception

Tags: java, maven, jsoup

I am having a hard time trying to add JSOUP maven respository to my project. When I add it to the pom file:

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
     <version>1.11.3</version>
   </dependency>
```

All my project dependencies fails (only for this project) including local projects dependencies

The error I get are:

> Fail to read artifact descriptor for org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.11.3
>   Missing artifact "all other dependencies" Missing artifact
>   Repository:Repository:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

My working pom file (without JSOUP) is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>eGRC</groupId>
  <artifactId>eGRC</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>eGRC</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>Repository</groupId>
      <artifactId>Repository</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>config</directory>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I tried Cleaning the project and Updating it, but it didn't work. Do you have any idea of how should I face this issue?

Comment: Is there any jar file of jsoup in your .m2 folder?

Comment: Yes, the following files are available at .m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.11.3 --
jsoup-1.11.3.pom.lastUpdated --
jsoup-1.11.3-javadoc.jar.lastUpdated --
jsoup-1.11.3-sources.jar.lastUpdated --
m2e-lastUpdated.properties

Comment: Delete .m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.11.3 folder and build it again. There isn't any jar file in your local maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.lastUpdated` files indicate that the file could not be downloaded, and this information is cached. So either the artifact is not in the repository, or you somehow cannot connect to it. If you find the issue, make sure that you build with parameter `-U`, so that the cached information in `.lastUpdated` is ignored.

Comment: I solved it opening the repository on my internet browser and manually downloading the files. I tried downloading other Maven repositories and had no issue.

Comment: If you are in a company network, this is often a proxy/firewall issue.